# Bearer Claims Identity not being set for GET Method but is set for POST methods

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.net Web API 2 (.net 4.7).

I am trying to get a bearer claim identity (Current User) in the controller for a GET request but the only identity which is there is an windows identity and not a bearer claim identity. When I do a POST request the bearer claim identity is provided.

How come this happens and is there any way to get the bearer identity claim to be set for a GET request? Is there a setting in my startup(class) OAuth options which I needs to set?

Note: the same result happens for both "RequestContext.Principal" and "User.Identity"

Startup.Auth.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    static Startup()
    {
        IClientService clientService = /* Newing up service */
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            Provider = new OAuthAppProvider(clientService),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(20),                
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    }
}
```

Auth Provider

```
public class OAuthAppProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private IClientService _clientService;
    public OAuthAppProvider(IClientService clientService)
    {
        _clientService = clientService;
    }

    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var username = context.UserName;
            var password = context.Password;
            Client client = _clientService.GetByCredentials(username, password);
            if (client != null)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, client.Username),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, client.Role)
                };

                ClaimsIdentity oAutIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType);
                context.Validated(new AuthenticationTicket(oAutIdentity, new AuthenticationProperties() { }));
            }
            else
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Error with provided Username or Password.");
            }
        });
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        if (context.ClientId == null)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide some code. How is your bearer authentication set up? In theory it shouldn't make a difference whether the request is `GET`, `POST` or any HTTP verb. Can you see the authentication header on the request in your `GET` action? Can you debug and see it being processed by whatever middleware you've implemented? Etc.

Comment: Added code to question.

Comment: Yes I can see the Authentication Header in the RequestContext.Requests.Headers

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see anything obviously wrong here. I see you're getting `Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType` but not setting it, but i guess that's not the prob since you `POST` works. I take it your `OAuthAppProvider` isn't being hit at all on the `GET` request?

Comment: Started randomly working so really do not know what the problem was.